# How does BGP filtering work to prevent routing hijacking?

Tags: network, routing

I've been reading for a while but yet do not properly understand how is BGP filtering used to prevent "attacks" such the recent [Indosat's problem](http://www.renesys.com/2014/04/indonesia-hijacks-world/).

Do **not** copy&paste Cisco's site, I have read all that information already.

Comment: Could be merged with: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/56069/15648

Comment: You might find [this Jeff Doyle's article on Cisco Subnet](http://www.networkworld.com/community/node/18454) interesting. Could you please also [edit] in the link to the Cisco site's explanation, so we know what you're referring to that you've already read? Thanks!